# Add random colour to animations

Tags: animation

I'm getting the hang of the animation tools for blender, but I need to add colour to my scenes, but I'd like to make the colours for my already existing animations, and future ones.

So I'd like my idle animation to pick one colour then the corresponding animation to be that same colour, and when the idle animation appears again a new random colour appears.

[image: picture of idle]

This is picture of idle character, but the idea is a player flicks the character at the world behind him, and splats on the surface, but I'd like to add in some colour, and It needs to be a random colour, each time the idle is reset.

[image]

So I need to add a random colour to the idle character, and the same colour to the corresponding animation, because the character goes in different direction, depending on which way the player flicks the character.
Thank you
R.D

Comment: It's hard to guess how your animations look like and which color you want to change, could you add an image of your animation and rephrase the question based on what we see in the image.

Comment: or is the problem more of a programming one?

Comment: Thanks for adding the images, you could achieve something similar by keyframing the color. This would work because you just want to render an animation. Otherwise I guess you would need to write python code in order to dynamically add colors (this approach would also work in a game).

Comment: After reading your text again, I noticed that you mention a player. Does this mean that you want to create something in the game-engine?

Comment: Thank you, I am also having a problem, with having the character flatten when it hits the world object.  any advice would be great.

Comment: This should be another question, please add also an image so that we can see what flattens (or is it just intersection).

Answer (score 1):

You could create vertex-groups for each ring that should get another color when when hit by the character like this:

[image]

Assign each ring its own material with the same color at the beginning. When the character hits the background object determine which polygon has been hit by a technique described here:
[How do I make a weapon shoot at the center of the screen?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/how-do-i-make-a-weapon-shoot-at-the-center-of-the-screen/13903#13903) find the face hit by the character and set the material's color to a random color, this would change the color of faces (because all of the them share this material).