# "Track to" and animations at the same time?

Tags: python, animation, game-engine, logic-bricks

For this question, I am trying to merge two things together. For the first part, I would like to have my empty that fires bullets to fire at the center of the screen while also having a spray pattern (sort of like the bullets shoot randomly, but I use an animation). I asked a question on how to have my bullets be fired to the center of the screen, and I received a great answer. I use a ray and an empty at the end of it, and the empty collides with objects. The empty that fires the bullets just tracks to it. If you do not understand, you can look at the QA in depth [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/how-do-i-make-a-weapon-shoot-at-the-center-of-the-screen). For the second part, I would like to have my bullets be fired in a "spray pattern." I achieved this using an animation on my empty that fires the bullets. For the question, I am trying to merge both of these things together. I would like my empty to point at the center of the screen while shooting in a pattern. Would I just need to apply both and it would work? Would the animation need to be removed? If you have any idea of how to achieve this, please post anything below. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the behavior that you want by parenting your empty with the recoil animation to the empty that tracks to the center of the screen.

[image]

**Tracks to the center**                         **Emits projectiles + plays recoil animation**

When your projectile emitting empty is parented to the tracking empty, it will still track to the center of the screen, and your bullets will vary in direction depending on your animation on that empty.

I think this is the effect you are trying to achieve[image]

Comment: So the parent is which empty? Sorry, I got a little confused. It seems that you said the parent is the empty that fires bullets. Is that right?