# Blender Game Logic Actuator

Tags: game-engine, armature

I managed to be able to control my player hand with mouse using mouse actuator.However, the hand move at the opposite direction i want. For example ,  when i move mouse down , the hand go up .And when i move my mouse around , the hand kind of turn around .[image: Twisted hand]

[image]

What is wrong with my actuator settings?
Here is the sample file:   http://www.mediafire.com/download/1sz9taf3bd8j28u/samp.blend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to reverse the hand direction set the sensitivity to -1.0 :

[image]

also pay attention to the local/global axis you are using ,the camera was turning in the right direction because you used the local axis while the hand local axis are not in the right orientation

Comment: I am really grateful that you help me . But i have a few questions. How do i set the hand into the the right orientation ? And the gun doesn't point towards the middle of the camera, how to make it point towards the middle? I tried adjusting the Min and Max . It works but not really accurate. Is there any other way?

Comment: @XavierChoo for now i think you should keep the hand as it is since it's working (although you can "apply Rotation" to change the local orientation but this may mess up the animation you have ) , and for aiming you can take a look at [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/how-do-i-make-a-weapon-shoot-at-the-center-of-the-screen)  and if you need more help just ask :)

Comment: Amazing ! Just what i need ! But i don't really understand the explaination of the py from David . His testing demo file was removed . Can you show me an example of it? That would really help me out.

Comment: I changed my rig into something that can move much more realistic . But the hand weight paint doesn't work as well like the previous one. So i am stuck at making it point towards the center. This is a personal request but can you help me check out my new rig and make the hand and head point towards the mouse? If only i finished this , my game will almost be complete since i know how to make good AI . Please help if you can . Sry for the trouble and thanks alot.Here is the file  http://www.mediafire.com/download/rpvgidxbadd517s/Sample.blend

Comment: @XavierChoo Hi there, this may be late but I'll try to work on that and since I have no prior experience I may take some time

Comment: I am out of words to express my gratefulness.Thank you so much!

Comment: so how is the progress going?

Comment: @XavierChoo sorry i got dragged away with other things, here is the [file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/34754), any feedback is welcome