# Rotate an object along face normal in the bge

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I have an empty that is at the center of the screen, it move to whatever you point at. An explanation on how to do so can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13790/how-do-i-make-a-weapon-shoot-at-the-center-of-the-screen).

I am looking to have a plane or empty *always* face *outwards* of *whatever object it is colliding with*. If this can't be done with an empty, I would be fine with a plane.

Here's a picture of what I don't want: (like this but in-game)

[image: pic1]

Here's a picture of what I do want: (like this but in-game, used wireframe as you cannot see in textured) See the plane is rotated to match the cube's face.

[image: pic2]

I am basically looking for the empty/plane (preferably empty) to face the outside of whatever it is colliding with.

Comment: I assume you want to get the colliding face's normal so you can add a bullet hit or some other effect, right?

Comment: @David♦ Yes, that is correct.

Comment: ..."according to an object's face normals" would be a more accurate title. If I understand what you're after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: logic bricks]
Set up the logic bricks as pictured above.

[image: demo Cone object, showing its axes]

This script will move an object (the cone) to the location of `ray.hitPosition` and then rotate it to point along the `ray.hitNormal` using [alignAxisToVect()](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.alignAxisToVect).
For this example, the cone is pointing along the positive z axis. If it was along a different axis, I would have to pass in the second parameter to `alignAxisToVect()`.

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()

ray = cont.sensors["Ray"]
cone = scene.objects["Cone"]

if ray.hitObject and cone is not ray.hitObject:
    cone.worldPosition = ray.hitPosition
    cone.alignAxisToVect(ray.hitNormal)
```

Example gif, showing the cone moving and rotating to match the underlying geometry in the game engine.

[image: animated gif]

#### [Blend File](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/547/)

Comment: There is no need to arctan anything. You can use KX_GameObject.alignAxisToVect(ray.hitNormal) which aligns the object's z-axis along the normal.

Comment: @Monster thanks for pointing me to that function, much simpler. edited my answer.